# data table filtering (multicolumn)

Tags: c#, filter, datatable

Hello I have a datatable that I would like to filter with a single textbox, non-case sensitive. In other words when a user starts typing into the textbox, I would like the `RowFilter` to display any rows that CONTAIN the typed information (again regardless of case).

My current code will only display exact matches and only for a single column ("ID"). There are a few other columns I want to include, i.e. "Title", "User Name", "Company", etc.

Any ideas?

```
private void searchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (searchTextBox.Text.Trim() != "")
   {
      gridToTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ID = " + searchTextBox.Text;
   }
   else
   {
      gridToTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;

   }

}
```

Comment: You can use LINQ to DataTable to replace RowFilter - it's much more versatile and allows creating your own custom filters. See example at http://codecorner.galanter.net/2012/03/06/replace-datatable-rowfilter-with-linq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` in the `RowFilter` and concat all flters with `OR`.

```
var rowFilter = string.Format(
        "ID LIKE '%{0}%' OR TITLE LIKE '%{1}%' OR Company LIKE '%{2}%' OR UserName LIKE '%{3}%'"
        , txtSearchID.Text
        , txtSearchTitle.Text
        , txtSearchCompany.Text 
        , txtSearchUserName.Text
    );  
gridToTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = rowFilter;
```

[`DataColumn.Expression Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)  (same syntax for `DataView.RowFilter`)

But to be honest, i would suggest to use [`LINQ-to-DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) instead since it's much more powerful.

For example:

```
DataTable tblFiltered = gridToTable.AsEnumerable()
                       .Where(r => r.Field<int>("ID").ToString().Contains(txtSearchID.Text) 
                                || r.Field<string>("TITLE").Contains(txtSearchTitle.Text)
                                || r.Field<string>("Company").Contains(txtSearchCompany.Text)
                                || r.Field<string>("UserName").Contains(txtSearchUserName.Text))
                       .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: 99% there...it doesn't like the column "User Name" with the space in it. unfortunately, there' names a lot to backtrack into renaming it entirely. any suggestions?

`A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SyntaxErrorException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Syntax error: Missing operand after 'name' operator.`

Comment: @ikathegreat: Then you need to enclose it with brackets: `[User Name]`.

Answer (score -1):

The grid provides three complementary methods of data filtering.
Row.Filtered- the easiest method of displaying or hiding data. However,it is doesn't support even-driven data model and therefore it is not useful for more complex applications. With this method the programmer has to control row visibility manually and to consider that data can be sorted or grouped and can have complex hierarchical structure.

IFilter interface -The most efficient and convenient filtering method. The programmer has to inherit IFilter interface and to implement IsFiltered method. This method uses row as argument for which the grid determines  whether filtering is required.

Graphical filters in columns.This feature enables the programmer to implement any graphical filter that can be used for interactive data filtering. Any graphical control placed in dropdown box can be used as a filter. Implementation of such filter is based on familiar UITypeEditor that can provide any user control more detail you can visit dapfor. com